# Why is the _bin_DeployableAssemblies folder specific to web applications?

Tags: asp.net, .net, inversion-of-control, console-application

The _bin_DeployableAssemblies folder was added in VS 2010 SP1 as a common way to pull in assemblies for which no hard dependency exists.

I believe it was originally added as a way to allow folks to bin-deploy MVC, but it seems useful in environments outside of web applications.  In particular, a lot of inversion of control scenarios will result in loosely coupled components that don't require a hard reference, but still require dependent assemblies to be located (usually in the bin directory).

I searched through the .targets files on my system, but the only references to _bin_DeployableAssemblies is in web-related targets.  This seems short-sighted and I'm curious if anyone knows why Microsoft would not include this functionality for other application types.

Comment: My understanding is that the whole concept of 'bin deployable' is related specifically to web applications, because you are deploying to an environment that you typically have no control over (shared hosting). If you're deploying a desktop application it's easier to package assemblies using an installer. This way you can even add them to the GAC, which in most web hosting environments is just not possible.

Comment: @michielvoo That's true, but it seems a bit silly to artificially limit the functionality to web applications.  In my case I think it would be nice not to need a custom post-build operation to copy in DLLs while I'm doing active development and testing.  An installer in that case feels way overboard.  I just wasn't sure if there was a really good reason they didn't include it (it's a bad idea, and this is why), or if it was more of a "we see a need for this on web apps but don't have time to research use cases for other apps" situation.