# MVC Application Created in Visual Studio 2012 is not working properly after deploying on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, visual-studio-2012

I have created a simple MVC3 application in Visual studio 2012. Earlier I was using VS2010. Both are currently Installed on my System. 
The Problem is that when I publish and Deploy the application on IIS It doesn't works.
It gives `Error Code 0x00000000`

I tried with different applications but problem remains the same. Any of the application created in VS2012 is not deploying Successfully. Please Help.

I am adding snapshot of publish and error message.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try to access a page rather than a directory. you may use `localhost:8090/mycontroller/` rather than `localhost:8090`.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you are publishing an mvc3 app.
If I remember correct for that version you either have to install mvc on the server or include mvc binaries in your output directory. 
There was a menu item for mvc project (right click on a project in solution explorer) to add mvc dependencies to some binpub folder. You should look for that.

oh and here is a Hanselman post on the topic
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BINDeployingASPNETMVC3WithRazorToAWindowsServerWithoutMVCInstalled.aspx

And another SO question: [Why is the _bin_DeployableAssemblies folder specific to web applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389506/why-is-the-bin-deployableassemblies-folder-specific-to-web-applications)

Comment: By default, the MVC DLLs aren't copied with the project. You need to go to the reference inside the project for the mvc libraries, and in the properties of each reference, choose the "Copy Local".
If this don't work, your server maybe don't have the .NET Version you need, if you built your app in a more recent version that the server has.

Comment: that is for mvc 3 yes.
Since v4 they are auto copied.

Comment: I tried to create a Mvc4 application but it didn't worked. Same error on deploying.

Comment: I also tried "Copy Local" to "True" all references, but it also didn't worked.. Please help..